# std::result_of syntax kerfuffle

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, result-of

I have the following (CUDA) function:

```
__device__ auto foo(my_class& x, my_function_ptr_type y ) {
    return [gen](my_class& x) { return x.set_y(y); };
}
```

And I want typedef its return value's type. I've fiddling with the std::result_of syntax, and can't get it quite right. This won't work:

```
using foo_return_type = std::result_of<decltype(foo(my_class{}, my_function_ptr_type{nullptr}))>::type;
```

Nor this:

```
using foo_return_type = std::result_of<decltype(foo(my_class, my_function_ptr_type))>::type;
```

Nor this:

```
using foo_return_type = std::result_of<foo>::type;
```

What *should* I have as the template-argument to `std::result_of`?

Notes:

- There's only one `foo()` in the namespace.
- No templates are involved (other than `std::result_of`...)
- C++11 or C++14, take your pick (but note that this is CUDA, so theoretically that could be an issue).
- Compiler: NVCC 10.1

Comment: Remove the `decltype` of the second variant and add a `&` to to `my_class`.

Comment: Do you want the return type of `foo` (which is some unnamed class generated by the lambda expression) or the return type of the lambda that `foo` returns?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Return type of foo, not of the lambda.

Comment: `using foo_return_type = decltype(foo(std::declval<my_class&>(), nullptr));` should do it. [Demo](https://rextester.com/UMM86015). Not sure what you hope to use this type for though.

Answer (score 1):

You need a function pointer type and the parameter types, then combine them in the format of `F(ArgTypes...)`. e.g.

```
using foo_return_type = std::result_of<decltype(&foo)(my_class&, my_function_ptr_type)>::type;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VCRACJFvRsNaiIXf)

---

You can also make your own type trait, if you don't stick to `std::result_of`. e.g.

```
template <typename F>
struct return_type_of_function {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_of_function<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};
```

then

```
using foo_return_type = return_type_of_function<decltype(foo)>::type;
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iwIZwL542AJtkRCe)